# SQL DISTINCT [Alternative Using]

Tags: sql, database, oracle, distinct

I have a simple query on Oracle.

```
SELECT DISTINCT City, Name, Surname FROM Persons
```

Is there any alternative sql query for the same query without `DISTINCT` ?

Comment: In my compiler, distinct word getting error strangly :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://awads.net/wp/2006/03/08/an-alternative-to-distinct/)

Example as;

```
select City
from (
  select City,
         row_number() over 
           (partition by City
            order by City) rownumber
    from Persons
         ) t
   where rownumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT City, Name, Surname FROM Persons
UNION
SELECT City, Name, Surname FROM Persons
```

Comment: That would just do the whole list twice.

Comment: @MPelletier: This would work... although it's probably not the most efficient way of doing it. You'd only get the whole list twice if using `UNION ALL`

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey Damn, I never saw that coming! @Diederik Hoogenboom, sorry for misjudging this answer.

Comment: @MPelletier No problem. But it is not the most efficient way of course. This looked like a philosophical question to me so I just thought I mentioned to next to the more complex answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT First(City), First(Name), First(Surname)
FROM Persons
GROUP BY City, Name, Surname
```